# Learning about Computer Vision

Tags: computer-vision

I am really intrigued by the field of computer vision and the potential it has. Are there any examples (preferably implemented in .NET) which I can study along with a reference book?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OpenCV (Open Computer Vision) is the most popular library, and it has been wrapped for C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Intel_OpenCV.aspx

Some discussion about this wrapper and the library in general is here:

http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/08/opencv-open-source-computer-vision-for.html

Answer (score 32):

#### Sample Vision Code

- [Vision Source Code](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecil/v-source.html) - Carnegie Mellon University
- [Open Source Computer Vision Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) - Sourceforge
- [Computer Vision Test Images](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecil/v-images.html)
- [libsift - Scale-Invariant Feature Transform implementation](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/tu-berlin-2006/libsift/)
- [C# wrapper for OpenCV](http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.com/2008/08/opencv-open-source-computer-vision-for.html)

#### Resources

- [Computer Vision Online](http://www.computervisiononline.com) - Computer Vision Online
- [Computer Vision "Home"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/cil/ftp/html/vision.html) - Carnegie Mellon University
- [Lecture on Vision Systems](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Vision_lecture/Vision_lecture_caller.html) - Cardiff School of Computer Science
- [Lectures on Computer Vision Systems](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Etpp/G5BVIS/lectures.html) - The University of Nottingham Computer Science Department
- [Feature Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)) - Wikipedia Article
- [Scale-Invariant Feature Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) - Wikipedia Article

#### Stack Overflow Questions

- [Where do I learn about Image Processing and Object Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432569/where-do-i-start-learning-about-image-processing-and-object-recognition)
- [Image Processing Textbooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207092/image-processing-textbook)
- [Computer Vision References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98438/computer-vision-reference)

Answer (score 15):

While the OpenCV library is interesting to use, it doesn't offer a lot of transparency as you learn. If you're interested in actually learning about the field, I would recommend looking into low-level image processing libraries and implementing your own Computer Vision applications. Once you've coded your own basic CV applications, using the OpenCV library becomes a *lot* easier. I would suggest the following topics to advance quickly through the basics:

- sobel operators for edge detection
- trying your hand at color segmentation
- reconstructing 3d information from stereo images using disparity maps

Here's a site with some good test images (http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-images.html).

I also found a good resource of course slides that cover the majority of these topics at (http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~tpp/G5BVIS/lectures.html)

Happy hacking =)

Answer (score 10):

Here's a large collection of code, toolkits, and apps you might find useful

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-source.html

Answer (score 8):

You could start by looking at some of the similar questions on this site:

- [where-do-i-start-learning-about-image-processing-and-object-recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432569/where-do-i-start-learning-about-image-processing-and-object-recognition)
- [image-processing-textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207092/image-processing-textbook)
- [computer-vision-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98438/computer-vision-reference)

I can also look at these two sites:

- http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/cil/ftp/html/vision.html
- http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/Vision_lecture/Vision_lecture_caller.html

The sites provide information, tutorials and code examples, even though they are not actively maintained anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is the OpenCV project on sourceforge with a book that you can get as well.  [You can see it here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/). However, that is not a .NET solution it is C

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Open Computer Vision Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/). It's much spoken of and looks promising. It even has an O'Reilly accompanying book :)

> The Open Computer Vision Library has >
>   500 algorithms, documentation and
>   sample code for real time computer
>   vision. Tutorial documentation is in
>   O'Reilly Book

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of work with [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) in the recent past and it seems to be a rather interesting modern algorithm for [feature detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(computer_vision)), which is one of the major (and perhaps more advanced) topics within machine vision. Someone has written a [C# library](http://user.cs.tu-berlin.de/~nowozin/libsift/) for SIFT with a pretty nice example that can automatically stitch together separate photographs of the same scene. Admittedly, this isn't a very complete answer, and I can't recommend a reference book, but hopefully it should be of some use to you anyway...

Answer (score 1):

The [AForge.NET library](http://www.aforgenet.com/) is pretty good and is written in C#, with the source available [here](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).

Supported features are:

- AForge.Imaging - library with image processing routines and filters;
- AForge.Vision - computer vision library;
- AForge.Neuro - neural networks computation library;
- AForge.Genetic - evolution programming library;
- AForge.Fuzzy - fuzzy computations library;
- AForge.MachineLearning - machine learning library;
- AForge.Robotics - library providing support of some robotics kits;
- AForge.Video - set of libraries for video processing etc.

The algorithms are maybe not as cutting edge/academic as some of the other answers but a lot of the engineering problems taken care of (getting video into your application, etc).