# What's the name for the type of computer vision that doesn't involve range sensors?

Tags: computer-vision, range, sensors

I'm just wonder if there's a specific name to the subset of computer vision that does not use range sensors, but instead only uses 2D images to gather data. This would include stereo vision, using a single moving camera, etc. Is there a name for the entire category of computer vision that does not use direct range data but instead only gets the range data through interpretation of the images? Thanks!

Comment: [Learning about Computer Vision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711057/learning-about-computer-vision?rq=1) has many links on this topic, and one of them may provide that information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [passive stereo as opposed to active depth sensing](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=active+passive+stereo).

Comment: Well, passive stereo is specifically for when you have two cameras with a known distance between them. I'm looking for the name which also encompasses when you have a single camera that moves and when you simply try to extract 3D information from a single image based on features.

Comment: Ok then. In that case it's simply structure-from-motion or multi view stereo. I've seen the terminology used interchangeably in the papers I've read, but my understanding is that structure-from-motion refers more to the sparse feature matching and bundle adjustment (i.e. recovering the camera pose) part, and multi view stereo is more about dense reconstruction, normally with the camera pose as input.

Comment: I'm sorry. The problem is I'm looking for the word that encompasses all of passsive stereo, structure-from-motion/multi-view-stereo, and simply trying to extract 3D information based on the features. I realize each of these names are correct for that individual case. However, I'm looking for a term that encompasses all these cases. Then again, I don't think these is one. So I'm going to pick your answer since it's made it more clear a name for this doesn't exist. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

Well we can call them as Structure from Motion.

Comment: But it's not always from motion. Such as the case with stereo vision.