# Object Recognition using Android API

Tags: android, image-processing, computer-vision

Is there any API in Android SDK which should recognize an object and return the name of the object.

Comment: refer  this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817684/object-recognition-using-matlab?rq=1)

Comment: might be this help you .....Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getClassName();

Comment: santosh: It didn't work :), thats why posted a question here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general objects in 3D, that is an unsolved problem in computer vision right now. A lot of researchers are working on it, but right now computers cannot reliably identify that an arbitrary object they haven't seen before is a "chair", for example. (If you think about it, such labeling actually requires a lot of judgment and world knowledge to know what kinds of things humans can sit on, and that's beyond the current state of AI for objects in general.)

There are algorithms that basically do a Google Image Search: they take a given picture and use some fairly advanced computer vision to find similar-looking pictures on the web (i.e. Google Goggles). There are APIs for those; check out
[Google goggles API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080731/google-goggles-api)

Those work well for 2D pictures, like posters and product logos, that always look exactly the same, but not for things like plants and animals.